# Performance mySql PHP - Closing days of the week

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

What would be the fastest way to run this to check for days of the week that a business is closed?

```
$closingDaysCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM businessClosingDays WHERE Bid='$Bid' LIMIT 1", $con);

if($closingDaysCheck) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($closingDaysCheck) >0) {
        while ($closed = mysql_fetch_assoc($closingDaysCheck)) {
            if((date("w", $finalDate) == 0) && ($closed[0] != 0)) { // SUNDAY
                $active = 'inactive';
            } else if((date("w", $finalDate) == 6) && ($closed[6] != 0)) { // SATURDAY
                $active = 'inactive';
            } else if((date("w", $finalDate) == 5) && ($closed[5] != 0)) { // FRIDAY
                $active = 'inactive';
            } else if((date("w", $finalDate) == 4) && ($closed[4] != 0)) { // THRUSDAY
                $active = 'inactive';
            } else if((date("w", $finalDate) == 3) && ($closed[3] != 0)) { // WEDNESDAY
                $active = 'inactive';
            } else if((date("w", $finalDate) == 2) && ($closed[2] != 0)) { // TUESDAY
                $active = 'inactive';
            } else if((date("w", $finalDate) == 1) && ($closed[1] != 0)) { // MONDAY
                $active = 'inactive';
            } else {
                $active = 'active';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the database, the last day is Sunday and it's closed:

```
CREATE TABLE `businessClosingDays` (
  `Bid` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `6` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `0` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `businessClosingDays` VALUES('9', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Patrick, I've test it following your advice.
Eventually I need it to check all the days in a month.
I tested with 1 day, which should be closed.
I create an array from mysql.
And I check if the day of the week of that date is in the array, which is. but for some reason doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$dateToCheck = 1327791600; // timestamp

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM businessClosingDays WHERE Bid = '9'");
while ($closedDays = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
echo $closedDays[0], $closedDays[1], $closedDays[2], $closedDays[3], $closedDays[4], $closedDays[5], $closedDays[6];
}

if (in_array(date("w", $dateToCheck), $closedDays)) {
echo "in it";
} else {
echo "not";
}
```

Comment: Please, can you kindly reveal to us what the variable $finalDate is?

Comment: Hi Zaf, sorry, $finaldate is each day of a month. Basically, this script builds a javascript PopUp Calendar. And checks to see if each day of the month, is Monday, Tues,... if Sunday is supposed to be closed, like in the example (hence the 1 in the database). then every day in the PopUp will be "inactive". @zaf

Comment: -1 for asking for the "fastest way" without a reason

Comment: Col, the reason is obvious. Just look at the code ;o) @Col. Shrapnel

Comment: I'd like to see some more context in regards to how you build the calendar to be able to improve my answer. Could you provide some code for the context of this snippet? I.e, loops, function calls whatever

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand Thanks PatriK, here is the entire for loop that goes thru all the days of 1 month to see if there are closed days of the week. http://pastebin.com/TfVaEL6k

Answer (score 2):

Now, I don't really understand what you mean with "fastest", since it'll probably just be microoptimizations at this point, but you could organize it a lot better logic-wise.

I would get rid of all the if-else clauses. Since you are interested in whether the the business is closed on a given day, you can just check that day.

Then the code would look something like this:

```
// Remember to escape your queries to prevent SQL-injection!
$query = sprintf (
   'SELECT * 
    FROM businessClosingDays 
    WHERE Bid='%s' 
    LIMIT 1'
   mysql_real_escape_string($Bid, $con)
);
$closingDaysCheck = mysql_query($query, $con);
if($closingDaysCheck) {
    // We only need to calculate this once, not in multiple if-else clauses
    $finalWeekday = date("w", $finalDate);

    // Default is that the store is open, right? And a value of 1 
    //means it's closed:
    $active = 'active';

    // Try to fetch the result. Since we use LIMIT 1, we can have
    // at most 1 row, so get rid of the while-loop.
    $closedAt = mysql_fetch_assoc($closingDaysCheck);

    // Now, see if we have any information of when the store is closed
    // and if we do and the store is closed on this day, change the
    // value to 'inactive'
    if(!empty($closedAt) && $closedAt[$finalWeekday] == 1) {
      $active = 'inactive';
    }
}
```

**Assumptions:** *I assume that we are only interested in whether the store is open on a given date, i.e. `$finalDate` and not a range of dates. If this assumption is true, then `finalDate` is not a good name for the variable in question. It should be named something along the lines of `dateToCheck` or similar.*

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, sorry, I didn't specify, that I actually have to go thru the entire month. See clarification to Zaf, on top ;o) @PatrikAkerstrand

Comment: Also it's possible that the business is closed more than 1 day, so we would need a while, or create a foreach with an array of all the closing days of the week.

Comment: I tested with one date, but eventually a need to go thru the entire month. I create an array, and I check if the date is in the array. But doesn't seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi PatriK, did you have time to check the entire for loop that goes thru all the days of 1 month to see if there are closed days of the week. pastebin.com/TfVaEL6k

Comment: Hey Sebastian. Not yet I'm afraid, me and the family have been ill. We're recovering now. I hope to get to it soon.

Comment: No hurry, it works this way, it just looks ugly. I hope you all get better, I suppose you're also going thru the cold wave.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look into MySQL's [COUNT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html). It can return the number of rows that matches your query.

Comment: Thanks Orolin, I just made 2 clarifications above, actually, I don't need to know how many days are inactive, but which days are inactive, since then I will build a PopUp Calendar based on the results. It works fine like this, but doesn't look nice ;o) @Orolin